# How to resolve the error "Cannot use import statement outside a module" in react-native

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, expo, babeljs, es6-modules

Okay I know what you are thinking.
Right now you are thinking that this error already has answers here in this awesome community. But trust me, I combed through every corner, but nothing solved it.

So what have I tried already?

1. I added the `"type": "module"` line to the `package.json` file; but error kept coming back.
2. I tried dozen different variations for the `babael.config.js` file and yeah absolutely nothing worked.

Here's the recent change.

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  env: {
    test: {
      plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
    },
  },
};
```

I got this error after adding the firebase-react-native sdk. Before that none existed. When I run `expo start` I get the following:

```js
\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\auth\lib\index.js:18
import {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
```

Do you know any solution for this?

THANKS!!!

Comment: is this code snippet your babel configuration?

Comment: @novonimo It is. ==> babel.config.js to be precise

Comment: thanks, so I try to guess the answer and I'm not sure about it, please feedback me about it.

Comment: which version of react-native you are using?

Comment: Absolutely mate @novonimo

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.63.4

Comment: I am using EXPO, just so you know

Comment: one of the silly actions is to change your "babel.config.js" to ".babelrc" and then remove the "module.exports", just keep the configuration which starts after modeule.exports = 
, somethings like this:

{
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  env: {
    test: {
      plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
    },
  },
};

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237758/discussion-between-on-the-way-to-success-and-novonimo).